# xcode multiple targets

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

We have an iPad game on the appstore and decided to make an iPhone version of it.
After adding a new target, modifying the necessary views and classes the game runs perfectly on both iPhone and iPad (devices and simulators).

My question is, do I have to upload the new iPhone version as a completely different app to itunesconnect or is there a way to use the same name/app id for both?

Will users who already purchased the iPad app have to pay again for the iPhone app?

Anyone who can shed some light on multiple targets and universal apps would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , You would have to upload the new **iPhone** app separately and the users who purchased your iPad app would have to *pay for the iPhone version again*. This is only when you have not developed a *universal* app in the beginning for both **iPhone** and **IPad**. If it was for both then there would not have been an issue. Also the app you would now put up as the **iphone** one cannot be the same name as of the **iPad** one as the name has been reserved for the **iPad** one only.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, much appreciated. what do you recommend in this case? universal app vs. 2 different apps? what is the best practice?

Comment: Thats totally your decision and if you have a plan of making the app for both the versions then you should make it universal... Also a game should be normally made for both versions .... :)